# How can I configure my travis.yml for Play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, travis-ci

I want to configure my travis.yml for Play framework 2.4.3 Java project, but I couldn't find anything about that.

This is my current `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java
sudo: false

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - oracle-java8-installer

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

env:
 PLAY_VERSION=2.4.3

before_script:
   wget http://downloads.typesafe.com/releases/play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip
   unzip -q play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip
script: play-${PLAY_VERSION}/play deps --sync

notifications:
email: false
```

As you know, Play framework use Activator since 2.3.8 version, and how can I download play framework 2.4.3 from full URL? Because http://downloads.typesafe.com/releases/play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip this URL is not working.

My Project Spec:

- Play Framework 2.4.3
- MySQL 5.7.9
- Hazelcast (Maybe could be Redis)
- Debian 8 (on cloud)
- Travis-CI (Pro)
- Github
- IntelliJ Idea 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project uses the standard project setup that activator provides, there's very little you need to do to integrate with Travis CI. I am not sure why you are downloading the framework, when sbt should be doing that for you.

All you need is a `.travis.yml` file at the root of the project with the following content:

For Java:

```
language: java
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
```

For Scala:

```
language: scala
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
```

Travis will find your projects sbt files and will fetch the Play Dependencies for you. See my [scala example here](https://github.com/RawToast/chousen-play/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Comment: @brhand The link should be working, I've just had to make a minor amendment (something irrelevant for this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try a maven repo:

wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-ws_2.10/2.4.3/play-ws_2.10-2.4.3.jar

PS: 'm not familiar with Activator; I looked at your question since it mentions Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0):

this config work for me, my project is play framework with java.

```
language: scala
sudo: true
scala:
- 2.11.6
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
install: true
```

Thanks.